# My step mom has a American bull massive and Rottweiler mixed dog and he smells awfully disgusting

Tags: dogs, bathing

He is huge and he hasn't had a bath in 3 years and he smells awful and I keep telling them it's bad for his health but they aren't listening I mean he smells like unbelievable disgusting the whole house smells like it and they get so mad when I tell them about it but it's disgusting and he is constantly iching and scratching and he is aggressive and just moody as hell and I believe he has ear mites and they won't even take him to the vet because he is aggressive and the vets have to put a muzzle on him please help me what could be the health issues